# Кнопки управления на панораме Yandex

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

столкнулся с такой проблемкой... У меня смещаются значки на кнопках...

Насколько заметил дается margin-left:0; но при каком условии я не могу понять... а так же еще сверху должен быть отступ...

P.S: два блока с панорамой имеют только такие стили:

```
width: 48%; 
height: 330px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P.S Исправил, но думаю тема может быть полезной... у меня на * стоял стиль box-sizing: border-box;, что вообщем то нормально... но для иконок нужен был box-sizing:content-box; т.е:

```
.ymaps-2-1-62-islets_maps-button__icon {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: CSS стили важны для корректной работы API, поэтому переопределять стили карты нельзя. Важно проверять, что стили страницы не влияют на карту.

Comment: и? из за карты я не буду прописывать каждому элементу box-sizing... *[class$="-islets_maps-button__icon"] и дело решено